# Creating a linestring from points using shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I am creating a linestring from points using shapely, but I could not generate the linestring using the points on my local system. This code is running fine on Google Colab. Is there any package dependency which I don't have installed on my system?

```
import shapely
from shapely import speedups
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point, LineString, Polygon

a = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])
a

Error massage 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-02826fee6746> in <module>
----> 1 a = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])
      2 a

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in __init__(self, coordinates)
     46         BaseGeometry.__init__(self)
     47         if coordinates is not None:
---> 48             self._set_coords(coordinates)
     49 
     50     @property

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in _set_coords(self, coordinates)
     95     def _set_coords(self, coordinates):
     96         self.empty()
---> 97         ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
     98         if ret is not None:
     99             self._geom, self._ndim = ret

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

ValueError: GEOSGeom_createLineString_r returned a NULL pointer
```

Comment: Try to update `numpy`. i don't know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075847/using-qgis-and-shaply-error-geosgeom-createlinearring-r-returned-a-null-pointer), the error message is an old problem, and you can fix it by changing the order of the import process like this:

```
import shapely
from shapely import speedups
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point, LineString, Polygon
import fiona
    
a = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])
```

Another way is to disable speedups:

```
import shapely
from shapely import speedups
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point, LineString, Polygon
speedups.disable()

a = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])
```